# Migration from GCM to FCM effects on current porduction apps

Tags: android, migration, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android app working on production environment and I don't know how to migrate from GCM to FCM. I don't have a copy of an old GCM app to explore the process. So, my concern is: If I try to upload the existing app to firebase and create a new firebase project, would my living GCM project can be affected and as a result would doing this make my app stop supporting my users to use GCM service?

Any help Appreciated,
Ayshine

Comment: when you connect your project with FCM its connection to GCM will be removed,.

Comment: Thanks! then I should not use the old version. Can I have a new FCM project with the same name as my GCM project?

Comment: yes. you can create FCM with same app name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to [migrate a GCM Client App for Android to FCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm), keep in mind that:

> - GCM and FCM SDKs **cannot co-exist** within an application.
> - GCM tokens retrieved via `GoogleCloudMessaging.register()` or `InstanceID.getToken()` will continue to work in FCM without any
>     modification or renewal.

So if you have an existing FCM project into which you would like to migrate GCM app and it's users, there are special steps you must perform.

> These special steps are required because the existing Firebase project
>   **will not be able to send messages** to tokens belonging to a completely
>   separate GCM project. Until all client app instances upgrade to your
>   Firebase app, you'll need to create a mapping between old GCM tokens
>   and the Firebase project.

For more information, follow this documentation on how to [Migrate GCM to an existing Firebase project](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-firebase-project).

Comment: Thanks, @jess for the answer. My app uses some open source plugins last updated date dates back to 6 years ago. So, It will take some time for me to get back to migrating GCM to FCM state. I will come back and update this thread if your suggestion worked or not.

Comment: Okay, hope it will help at your end :)

Comment: In my case, I added an FCM project with a different name. Now my current app on prod is working fine with GCM and my new app working with FCM just fine.

Comment: Cool! Glad it helps :)